# "fill between" from pgfplots is placed behind other objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following is a (more or less) minimal example illustrating my problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, clip bounding box=default tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \fill[fill=red] (1,1) -- (3,1) -- (2,2) -- cycle; %%line A
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path=A, domain=1:3] {2-abs(x-2)};
        \draw[name path=B, thick, black] (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:3,1);
        \addplot[thick, fill=red] fill between[of=A and B] ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For "typical" elements of a tikz picture, they are drawn "over" the existing elements. For example, the triangle drawn in line "A" above is placed "above" the blue rectangle (i.e. it hides part of the rectangle).

In contrast to this, the second triangle drawn using the "fill between" option from pgfplots **is not**  placed "above" the blue triangle, even though it is drawn afterwards.

Why is this the case? Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Essentially, I want to use the area filled using "fill between" to be used for clipping. If there is an easier way to do this, I would appreciate any hints.

Finally, I want to remark that the "fill between" area in my actual application is **not** simply a triangle, so that drawing it directly (i.e. without "fill between") is not possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `on layer=main` as an option of `fill between`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, clip bounding box=default tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \fill[fill=red] (1,1) -- (3,1) -- (2,2) -- cycle; %%line A
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path=A, domain=1:3,on layer=axis foreground] {2-abs(x-2)};
        \draw[name path=B, thick, black] (1,1) -- (3,1);
        \addplot[fill=red] fill between[of=A and B,on layer=main];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]